# Running SQL Server query in Remote Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I have three SQL Servers A, B and C. I am trying to run a same query like `select @@servername` from A server and run the same query in B and C from Server A. I am loading this results in a server A table.  Please let me know how to accomplish this one.

Comment: Please show what you tried and explain how it didn't work (in the question not comments).

Comment: Are your 3 instances *really* 2008, 2008R2 and 2012? 2 of them are therefore completely unsupported, and the last last barely more than a year of support left. Time to sort out that upgrade path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run the inserts from the two remote servers using `OPENQUERY` which essentially runs the select locally on the remote server to be able to use the proper local indexes etc.

```
insert into localTableOnA (col1,col2,...)
select col1,col2,... from [dbname].dbo.[tablename]  --on ServerA

insert into localTableOnA (col1,col2,...)
select col1,col2,... from openquery([ServerB],'select col1,col2,... from [dbname].dbo.[tablename]')

insert into localTableOnA (col1,col2,...)
select col1,col2,... from openquery([ServerC],'select col1,col2,... from [dbname].dbo.[tablename]')
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have a procedure in Server A and I have to  run that procedure in B and C also.  I don't have that procedure in B and C. I have to run server A procedure to get the results of B and C. What need to be done to resolve this issue.

Comment: @Test If the stored procedure only exists on Server A, then it can only be run there.  Within that SP, you can query to the tables on Server B or C as above.

Answer (score 1):

You can make using linked servers.

1- WITHIN A instance

```
INSERT INTO [DatabaseName].[SchemaName].[TableName] (...) SELECT ... FROM [B].[DatabaseName].[SchemaName].[TableName];
INSERT INTO [DatabaseName].[SchemaName].[TableName] (...) SELECT ... FROM [C].[DatabaseName].[SchemaName].[TableName];
```

2- WITHIN A instance (Dynamic SQL)

```
EXEC ('INSERT INTO [A].[DatabaseName].[SchemaName].[TableName] (...) SELECT ... FROM [DatabaseName].[SchemaName].[TableName]') AT [B];
EXEC ('INSERT INTO [A].[DatabaseName].[SchemaName].[TableName] (...) SELECT ... FROM [DatabaseName].[SchemaName].[TableName]') AT [C];
```

3- WITHIN Other instance

```
INSERT INTO [A].[DatabaseName].[SchemaName].[TableName] (...) SELECT ... FROM [DatabaseName].[SchemaName].[TableName];
```